# PythonRegEx in Excel can i use module re, or another?

Tags: python, pandas

Good afternoon, how to use the PythonRegEx module re in Excel data to get data from the example: `#0000002947 _ _ 0 _ PK2/6700094735` only the last `PK2/6700094735`, this means that it writes out/searches for the first PK and then writes out all the data that is on the right side.

My code

```
    while ('__' in opis):
        opis = opis.replace('__', '_',)

    try:
        order = opis.split('#')[1].split('_')[1]
    except:
        pass
    if not order:
        try:
            order = opis.split('_')[-1]
        except:
            if df[i]['KAT FI'] == 'Kat ZKP':
                order = re.findall("PK+\w", opis)
            else:
                order = ""
```

Comment: Please include a _small_ subset of your data as a __copyable__ piece of code that can be used for testing as well as your expected output for the __provided__ data. See  [mre], and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/15497888) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that in general, your text will have the same format as the example you give:

> #0000002947 _ _ 0 _ PK2/6700094735

The code sample that will extract the last part: PKX/XXXXXXXXXX, with X being some digit is following:

```
import re
your_text = "#0000002947 _ _ 0 _ PK2/6700094735"
regex_pattern = r"#\d{10}\s_\s_\s\d\s_\s(PK\d\/\d{10})"
last_group = re.search(regex_pattern, your_text).group(1)
assert last_group == 'PK2/6700094735'
```

Hope it helps. It might be the case that you need to update regex in order to fit your general problem. If you show me more examples I could update regex pattern accordingly.